# Error opening project in QGIS

Tags: qgis

When I try to open a project in QGIS unexpectedly quits immediately without any error messages. Now, I open a new project with the same shapefile, when I try to edit or make filters QGIS closes promptly. What should I do to recover the project? Should I reinstall the program?

Comment: have you tried to open it with an older version? Do you think a shapefile is corrupt or the .qgs / .qgz file?

Comment: I have not tried to open any older version. I think it might be the file. qgs. The shape file I can open it but I can't apply any filter. Could it have anything to do with CRS?

Comment: Sounds more like corrupt data. Can you post the data to see if others can try to repair it, or give you guidance on what is actually wrong with it?

Comment: I can post, would it have to be the whole file?

Comment: Ideally, yes, the file as you are using it.

Comment: It is too large, bumps into character constraints.